# Tizen Application still "UNREGISTERED" after request approved for Push Service

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

My Tizen push messaging service request has been approved. However when I go to register to the push service, it responds by outputting to the console that the state is 'UNREGISTERED'. The app itself will run as a wearable web-app and is being tested currently on Tizen's wearable emulator. It works and updates the SQL database appropriately using AJAX, however, the push notifications and the push API in general from Tizen have been problematic to implement. I tried to post to Tizen forums, however, they are mostly in Korean and I don't see where I can post to it. I need to know what else is required to successfully register and push notifications to Tizen's push server via the web-app running on the wearable emulator. Thanks for your time!

```
##config.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" id="http://yourdomain/TAUBasicdemo" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
            <tizen:application id="4MgeHxcwvw.TAUBasicdemo" package="4MgeHxcwvw" required_version="3.0"/>
            <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/push"/>
            <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/notification"/>
            <tizen:privilege name="http://www.tizen.org/privileg/internet"/>
            <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
            <content src="index.html"/>
            <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.push"/>
            <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal"/>
            <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/web.service"/>
            <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/watch_app"/>
            <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/web.service"/>
            <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/network.internet"/> 
            <icon src="icon.png"/>
            <name>TAUBasicdemo</name>

            <tizen:profile name="wearable"/>
            <tizen:setting background-support="disable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
        </widget>

##notification.js
        //------------------ NOTIFICATION REGISTRY -----------------------
        /*eslint-disable*/
        /* Define the error callback */
        function errorCallback(response) {console.log('The following error occurred: ' + response.name); }

        /* Define the registration success callback */
        function registerSuccessCallback(id) { console.log('Registration succeeded with id: ' + id); }

        /* Define the state change callback */
        function stateChangeCallback(state) {

            if (state === 'UNREGISTERED') {
                /* Request application registration */
                console.log('The state is changed to: ' + state);
                tizen.push.register(registerSuccessCallback, errorCallback);
            } else if (state === 'REGISTERED') {
                /* Gets unread push notifications */
                console.log('The state is changed to: ' + state);
                tizen.push.getUnreadNotifications();
            }
        }

        //------------------- NOTIFICATION RECEIVING -----------------------

        /* Define the notification callback */
        function notificationCallback(notification) 
                { console.log('A notification arrives.'); }

        tizen.push.connect(stateChangeCallback, notificationCallback, errorCallback);

        var registrationId = tizen.push.getRegistrationId();
        if (registrationId !== null) {
            console.log('The registration id: ' + registrationId);} 
        else { console.log('UNREGISTERED STILL');} 

        //-----------------HANDLING LAUNCH FROM PUSH SERVICE -----------------------
        var requestedAppControl = tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().getRequestedAppControl().appControl;

        var pushMessage;

        for (var i = 0; i < requestedAppControl.data.length; ++i) {
            if (requestedAppControl.data[i].key === 'http://tizen.org/appcontrol/data/push/launch_type') {
                /* Launch type is 'registration_change' or 'notification' */
                var appData = requestedAppControl.data[i].value[0];
                console.log('launch_type: ' + appData);
                if (appData === 'registration_change') {
                    /* Launched due to change in the registration state */
                } else if (appData === 'notification') {
                    /* Launched due to a notification */
                    try {
                        /* Retrieve the latest message */
                        var pushMessage = tizen.push.getPushMessage();
                        /* Handle the retrieved message */
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error.name + ': ' + error.message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //------------MSG RETRIEVE WHEN LAUNCHED FROM PUSH SERVICE --------- 

        if (pushMessage) {
            console.log('notification received on ' + pushMessage.date + ' from: ' + pushMessage.sender);
            console.log('Details:');
            console.log(' - data: ' + pushMessage.appData);
            console.log(' - alert message: ' + pushMessage.alertMessage);
            console.log(' - message: ' + pushMessage.message);
            console.log(' - session: ' + pushMessage.sessionInfo);
            console.log(' - request ID: ' + pushMessage.requestId);
            console.log(' - type: ' + pushMessage.type);
        }

##index.html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/tau/mobile/theme/default/tau.css"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
            <!-- load theme file for your application -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <script src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/tau/mobile/js/tau.js"></script>
            <script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
            <script src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
            <script src="js/notification.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        </head>

        <body>
        <!--     <div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main"> -->
        <!--         <header> -->
        <!--             <h2 class="ui-title">TAU Basic</h2> -->
        <!--         </header> -->
        <!--     </div> -->

            <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here!</button>


            <p align="center">Start Age Confirmation</p>
            <p id="demo"></p>

           <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var txt;
                    var content = "";
                    var ofAge_21 = confirm("Is the customer older than 21?");
                    var file = "http://10.146.3.164/process.php";

                    if (ofAge_21 == true) {
                        txt = "Customer OVER 21.";
                        content = "INSERT INTO age_confirmation_records (Age_Range) VALUES (21)";

                    } else {
                        var ofAge_18 = confirm("Are they older than 18?");
                        if (ofAge_18 == true) {
                            txt = "Customer BETWEEN 18-21.";
                            content = "INSERT INTO age_confirmation_records (Age_Range) VALUES (18)";
                        } else {
                            txt = "Customer UNDER 18.";
                            content = "INSERT INTO age_confirmation_records (Age_Range) VALUES (0)";
                        }
                    }
                    alert("CONFIRMED: " + txt);
                      //POST the SQL command you want to execute to the process.php file
                    $(document).ready(function() { 
                                $.post(file, { sql_insert: content },
                                    function(data, status) {
                                        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); }, 'html'); 
                        });

                }
            </script> 

        </body>
        </html>
##output: 
    The web console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, 
    console.error) has been disabled.
    To activate it, you should launch project with Debug mode.
    file:///js/notification.js (34) :UNREGISTERED STILL
    file:///js/notification.js (14) :The state is changed to: UNREGISTERED
    file:///js/notification.js (4) :The following error occurred: TimeoutError
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with privilege
I addition to feature you also need to declare the privilege in the manifest.

```
<privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/push"</privilege>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: that is the first privilege I have  in the config.xml posted, and I had the feature as well.

Comment: Please check if pushd daemon is active in the emulator.